# Событие onblur порождает бесконечный цикл с alert/focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, alert

Нижеприведённый код после `blur` из пустого поля ввода бесконечно выдаёт `alert`.

Почему?
В каких браузерах/ОС наблюдается это поведение?

---

**ОС**: *Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS*
**Браузер**: *Google Chrome 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit)*

```js
let limit = 0; // Ограничиваем число алертов, этот limit не относится к вопросу
function valid(el) {
  if (!el.value && limit++<3) {
    alert('Value is empty');
    el.focus();
  } else limit = 0;
}
```

```html
<input onblur="valid(this)">
```

---

***Дополнение:***
Выполнение `el.focus` на другой итерации `event loop` прерывает порочный круг(хотя и не всегда):

```
function valid(el) {
  if (!el.value) {
    alert('Value is empty');
    setTimeout(() => el.focus());
  }
}
```

Comment: Почему? Возможно потому что, при вызове окна, сразу же фокусится `input`, и при нажатии на кнопку в `alert'e`, срабатывает `blur` поля ввода.

Comment: Разве `focus` не должен вызываться только **после** закрытия диалога `alert`?

Comment: @vp_arth, ты мог бы добавить небольшой счётчик вместо вот этого предупреждения(Не выполняйте код).

Comment: @vp_arth хороший вопрос, ответ на который не так очевиден, как казалось. В кач-ве совета могу предложить `el != document.activeElement` в условии.

Comment: [bugs.chromium.org: onblur event is going to infinite loop.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=666205)

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, особенно информативен [комментарий](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=666205#c20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема растет из того факта, что в браузере Chrome скрипты работают в UI-потоке, а этот самый поток блокируется модальным окном (блокировка потока модальным окном - это особенность ОС или графической библиотеки, а не браузера).

Получается вот такой сценарий:

1. Вызывается alert
2. У окна пропадает фокус, в очередь посылается событие blur
3. Пользователь закрывает alert
4. Скрипт вызывает focus и возвращает управление очереди событий
5. Из очереди достается событие blur и вызывается

Вообще говоря, событиям focus и blur "доверять" нельзя никогда, независимо от браузера - такова их природа. Просто потому что фокусом элемента всегда управляет пользователь, который может взаимодействовать с браузером быстрее чем ваш скрипт выполняется (например, если используются инструменты для автоматизации ввода). Кроме модальных окон работу вашего скрипта могут нарушить Punto Switcher, хранилище паролей или какой-нибудь инструмент для людей с ограниченными возможностями.

События focus и blur всегда чуть-чуть опаздывают, и дополнительная проверка вроде `el === document.activeElement` не помешает даже в нормально работающих браузерах:

```
function valid(el) {
  if (el === document.activeElement) return;
  if (!el.value) {
    alert('Value is empty');
    el.focus();
  }
}
```

PS вообще говоря, не отпускать фокус ввода и спамить алертами - плохая идея сама по себе, без всяких багов.

Хорошей практикой является отображения ошибок валидации рядом с заполняемой формой, с запретом отсылки невалидной формы.

Answer (score 0):

Это известный баг Chromium: [#666205](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=666205) (Спасибо [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy))

27 февраля этот баг был закрыт с меткой <kbd>Won't Fix</kbd>:

> В соответствии с тем, что утверждает `@adamk` из команды V8, моя идея c `async/await`
>   совершенно нереализуема, потому что этот примитив недостаточно
>   мощный/динамичный.   Внешняя функция с `await`, должна быть помечена как
>   `async` внутри на этапе компиляции, чтобы создать некоторые глобальные
>   таблицы.   В тот момент, когда выполняется `alert`, это сделать
>   невозможно.
>
> Итак, я не думаю, что у нас есть нечто лучшее, чем <kbd>Won't
>   Fix</kbd> @aelias

С другой стороны, workaround, предложенный [@SLy_huh](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229667/sly-huh) работает вполне адекватно:

```js
function valid(el) {
  if (el === document.activeElement) return;
  if (!el.value) {
    alert('Value is empty');
    el.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<input onblur="valid(this)">
```

Comment: Что-то вы что-то совсем странное процитировали. Там человек предлагал костыль и его отклонили, основное обсуждение закончилось раньше.

Comment: Стоило бы процитировать комментарии 20 с описанием проблемы и 39, где и написано почему так происходит. Также в нем был предложен костыль, от которого и отказались в процитированном вами комментарии.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, если есть желание - доведите ответ до ума. Я просто процитировал реплику совпадающую с датой закрытия бага.