# Alert не дает переключить вкладку в Chrome

Tags: javascript, alert

Доброго времени!

Есть html-форма. На нее навешано событие потери фокуса. После него происходит проверки правильности заполнения, если есть ошибки, выскакивает alert.
Проблема в том, что переключение вкладки в браузере тоже воспринимается, как потеря фокуса формы. 
Если форма имеет фокус и в этот момент пользователь переключает вкладку, запускается проверка и выскакивает alert. В мозилле это все терпимо, он не мешает переключить вкладку, но в хроме, alert не позволяет покинуть текущую страницу. Если не запретить выводить всплывающие окна, а просто кликать на OK, проверка отрабатывает раз за разом и окно выводится снова и снова.

Пыталась прицепить какую-нибудь проверку на переключение вкладки, но:
1 - событие переключения отрабатывает позже события потери фокуса формы
2 - если кликнуть на алерт, вкладка снова получает фокус и проверка перезапускается.

Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: _Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему?_ - не использовать alert. Это самое лучшее решение.

Comment: @Grundy Я бы с радостью, но, увы, это не мой код)

Comment: Тогда по хорошему: никак.

Comment: @Grundy почему-то я так и думала((

Comment: В качестве обходного пути, не очень хорошего: можно переопределить  функцию alert: `window.alert = function(){...}` и в переопределенной функции уже определять что и как надо показывать.

Comment: а обязательно нужен именно стандартный alert? может написать свой <div> подобие?

Comment: Так это ж дубликат [моего вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628036/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-onblur-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-%D1%81-alert-focus)

Comment: @qpeela по возможности верстку лучше не трогать)

Comment: @vp_arth, если дубликат - проголосуй

Comment: @vp_arth ох, правда. что я должна сделать? удалить?

Comment: @FurryCat, там есть в ответах рабочий хак с проверкой `document.activeElement`.

Comment: Нет, удалять не нужно, нужно по хорошему кнопочку нажать, что нашли ответ там.

Comment: @vp_arth я очень извиняюсь, а где эта кнопочка?))

Comment: @FurryCat, уже ничего не нужно делать. Задавайте новые вопросы и получайте ответы! Удачи)

Answer (score 0):

У меня только одна идея появилась - принудительно убирать фокус с поля ввода перед выводом alert. Тогда, по крайней мере, проверка не перезапускается после его закрытия.
Но остается проблема - фокус остается на текущей вкладке и приходится еще раз переходить.

Comment: что-то я не понимаю: если ты можешь менять обработчик - почему не заменить alert На нормальные javascript модальные окна, которые не блокируют выполнение скрипта

Comment: @Grundy изменить тут верстку намного сложнее, чем дописать пару строчек JS (в организационном плане)

Comment: По сути добавить вызов диалога можно без изменения верстки